# DNSmasq configuration woes, how to make DHCP names served out of DNS entries

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, dhcp, dnsmasq

My DNSmasq configuration is as follows:

```
dhcp-range=private,192.168.128.100,192.168.128.200
dhcp-range=public,192.168.129.100,192.168.129.200
dhcp-option=private,option:router,192.168.128.1
dhcp-option=private,option:dns-server,192.168.128.1
dhcp-option=public,option:router,192.168.129.1
dhcp-option=public,option:dns-server,192.168.129.1

dhcp-boot=net:private,pxegrub.img,suo,192.168.128.8

dhcp-host=00:16:b6:d9:bd:58,net:private,192.168.128.1,poks
dhcp-host=00:13:d4:64:11:c3,net:private,192.168.128.7,keshi
dhcp-host=00:0e:a6:f9:0a:f4,net:private,192.168.128.8,suo
dhcp-host=00:22:15:14:df:07,net:private,192.168.128.9,ranbo
dhcp-host=52:54:00:c5:c4:ac,net:private,192.168.128.10,mythbox

domain=i.naked.iki.fi
server=/i.naked.iki.fi/
no-hosts
```

However, when attempting to resolve the addresses from the DNS server, the dhcp-host addresses are not answered:

```
root@poks:~# host keshi.i.naked.iki.fi 192.168.128.1
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.128.1
Address: 192.168.128.1#53
Aliases: 

Host keshi.i.naked.iki.fi not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
root@poks:~# host keshi. 192.168.128.1
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.128.1
Address: 192.168.128.1#53
Aliases: 

Host keshi. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
root@poks:~# host 192.168.128.7 192.168.128.1
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.128.1
Address: 192.168.128.1#53
Aliases: 

Host 7.128.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

What am I configuring wrong? How can I get DNS to answer for those hosts without adding separate "address" lines for them. I'd also like the reverse records served properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: heh, the heading got somehow mightily garbled :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's quite what you want, but I do something similar except that I put just the MAC to name mapping in the dnsmasq.conf and put the name to IP mapping in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Thanks, that is an option for me. However, I'd like the dnsmasq configuration to be completely standalone, if I can manage...

Comment: Actually, now that I read the dnsmasq documentation again, it seems that dnsmasq answers the DHCP addresses for *active* leases only - or atleast so it seems. So it might be that your solution is indeed the only one without specifying the addresses by hand.

Answer (score 0):

add infinite as lease time, so the lease is always active